# Meaning of "device" and "mountpoint" in docker volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to clarify the meaning of the "device" and "mountpoint" when I do the command

`docker volume inspect`

in Postgres container. I manually created `test_postgresdb_vol_2` folder in `/user/data/test_postgresdb_vol_2` to store persist the data from container, but now I'm confusing since I have two different paths. Can you clarify what is happening and what is the meaning of 
"device" path and "mountpoint" path.

Example of volume inspect:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "...",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            ....
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_pgdata/_data",
        "Name": "test_pgdata",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/user/data/test_postgresdb_vol_2",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Example of docker-compose:

```
postgres:
  container_name: postgres
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
  environment:
    ...
    PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
       o: bind
       type: none
       device: /user/data/test_postgresdb_vol_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those details in the `docker volume inspect` output are implementation details that can be safely ignored.

Internally, the current standard implementation of Docker named volumes gives them a filesystem presence inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.  In this case, you've told Docker that the volume should actually be created via the **mount**(2) system call, and more specifically as a bind-type mount.  The options you see could be parameters to **mount**(8)

```
/sbin/mount -o bind $DEVICE $MOUNT_POINT
```

You might notice that the `Driver` and `Options` match things you've specified directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file, `pgdata` matches the name of the volume, `test` matches the name of the current directory (and more specifically the Compose project name, should you override that), and `test_pgdata` where it appears is a combination of the two.

None of this matters to standard application code.  From the `docker-compose` file you've shown, you declare that the named volume is `local` and backed by a specific host directory, and it mounts into the `postgres` container on a specific path.  The `inspect`-type commands produce low-level debugging data that you almost never need.

Comment: So that means that all the postgrest container data will be stored in "/user/data/test_postgresdb_vol_2", right?

Comment: Yes (I'd expect to see a `pgdata` subdirectory there).

Comment: Since the relational database data is completely opaque to you, using the default named-volume storage here is a reasonable choice too (delete all of the options under `pgdata:`).  Of note, on a MacOS host, this will be visibly faster.

Comment: I cannot upvote more than once to show support for "using the default named-volume storage": use that in _almost all cases_ unless you know you need something else. At our company (Windows workstations) we've had nothing but problems with host-mounted folders - especially with databases - but never a single issue with docker volumes. However, we mount from a SAN in production, which is a special case.